# How can i set outline to a button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to set outline to a button and i tried

```
.btn{
  border: 1px double #A8A8A8;
  outline: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

It worked well in chrome... But it exhibits different behaviour in firefox... I knew that firefox reacts differently to outline as it draws outside the box-shadow...

Is there any other way to achieve this ???? Please help with some suggestions... 
I required like the one in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/JR7Hj/80/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try imitating this effect with box shadows. Unfortunately that flattens a tiny portion of the original button's gradient. If your original button was flat, however, this wouldn't be a problem. Here's a comparison screenshot:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/JR7Hj/83/

```
.btn {
border: 1px double #A8A8A8;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px  #f5f5f5 inset, 0 0 0 3px  #A8A8A8 inset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way (requires no css3):

```
.btn {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    border: 4px double #A8A8A8;
}

.btn:active {
    padding: 5px 13px;
    border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/JR7Hj/88/